# How to get value of specific XML child with PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml, redmine

I need to get the value of the custom_field "NewTitle" (ID 6) which is nested inside the child "custom_fields" of the following XML:

```
<issues total_count="63" offset="0" limit="100" type="array">
<issue>
<id>65</id>
<project id="7" name="ProjectName"/>
<tracker id="7" name="TrackerName"/>
<subject>MySubject</subject>
...
<custom_fields type="array">
<custom_field id="4" name="OrderType">
<value>Project</value>
</custom_field>
<custom_field id="26" name="ExtID">
<value>246558</value>
</custom_field>
<custom_field id="25" name="Area" multiple="true">
<value type="array">
<value>Process</value>
<value>System</value>
</value>
</custom_field>
<custom_field id="6" name="NewTitle">
<value>ABCDEF</value>
</custom_field>
...
<custom_field id="20" name="KST">
<value/>
</custom_field>
<custom_field id="11" name="LKF">
<value>3</value>
</custom_field>
<custom_field id="17" name="Link">
<value>XXX</value>
</custom_field>
</custom_fields>
<created_on>2015-12-14T08:00:03Z</created_on>
<updated_on>2016-01-28T09:07:20Z</updated_on>
<closed_on/>
</issue>
</issues>
```

Can somebody tell me how to do that with PHP? I only managed to display values of the main fields. For example the subject:

```
foreach ($xml->issue as $issue){
        if((string) $issue->tracker['id'] == 7){
            echo $issue->subject.'<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: user simplexml_load_string($XMLData)...and then you can iterate over the xml tags at any level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SimpleXML combined with an xpath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($your_xml_here);
$fields = $xml->xpath("//custom_field[@name='NewTitle']");
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // do sth. useful here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific about the key(s) to select the `<value>` you want.

I assume by your example that you want to select...

- the `<value>` of a parent `<custom_field>`
- having the attributes `name = "NewTitle"` and `id = "6"`
- having an `<issue>` ancestor with a child `<tracker>` with an attribute `id = "7"`

#### `xpath` is a fine solution to get to that value directly without iteration. It is like `SQL` for `XML`.

1. select the right `<issue>`:

   ```
   /issues/issue[tracker/@id='7']
   ```

   Note how `/` is separating parent from child, conditions are within `[]`,  attributes have `@`.
2. within that issue, select a `<custom_field>`with the given attributes:

   ```
   (...)/custom_fields/custom_field[@name='NewTitle'][@id='6']
   ```
3. then get the `<value>` children (can be more than just 1):

   ```
   (...)/value
   ```

Combined:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$values = $xml->xpath("/issues/issue[tracker/@id='7']/custom_fields/custom_field[@name='NewTitle'][@id='6']/value");
```

`$values` is an array containing single `<value>` nodes, or an empty array:

```
foreach ($values as $val) 
    echo $val->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<value>ABCDEF</value>
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/509835

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a texteditor on hand atm nor am I able to try it out myself but this should do the trick and give you an idea how to itterate through xml nestings.

```
foreach ($xml->issue as $issue){
    foreach ($issue['custom_field'] as $custField){
        echo $custField['value'];
    }
}
```